# how to minimize resource drain of port listener when data transfer is only secondary function

Tags: java, sockets

I have a program whose primary function is to perform computations. I then want a client program to be able to ping the server program and receive a response associated with the state of the main program and the progress of the computation.

I need the server to be listening to a port yet not have the listener consuming too many resources that would be better spent on the computation.

The two ways I've thought about doing it so far are:

1. having a single thread constantly listening
2. (since I know the IP addresses of all the client machines in
   advance) having the computational computer act as the client and the
   recipients of the data act like the servers. I realize this is
   counter-intuitive, but the the client (the computer doing the work)
   could simply send out a packet containing the data to any servers
   currently listening to the port on a sporadic basis and would
   therefore exhaust the resources on a less frequent basis.

Neither of these options feel like they are the best option available, but lacking experience using sockets, I don't know what my best option would be.

So to avoid this sounding like I'm asking for opinions, I would simply like you to state if you've encounter a similar scenario, and how you accommodated it. No opinions about which is better than which, just quantifiable facts about what options there are out there.

Also, I've looked at questions discussing the difference between server sockets and RMI and have concluded that for my scenario, RMI would not be the best option since the computer receiving the data won't be doing any computations of its own. But please correct this train of thought if it is incorrect.

Comment: As always when it comes to performance related questios: Have you profiled? How much slower is the computation if you have a thread accepting / processing progress queries? My guess: Between none and not measurable. Keep it simple, focus on readability and maintainability.

Comment: Why not simply implement a "RESTful" web service that clients could query to obtain status. You could use Java NIO so you would not need multiple threads to handle each simple client query. How is your server hosted?

Comment: This might be a noobish question, but after looking into RESTful, it seems like its for webservers, I just want to make sure, I wont have to have a dedicated hosting or web URL or anything will I? The server program will simply be running on my home computer hooked up to the internet

Comment: German over engineering...

Comment: @Hannes you mean like how NASA developed a million $ pen that works in space? might be over engineered but it sure put Russia's simple graphite pencil in its place

Comment: @Schrodinger's_hat That's an urban legend you're propagating. Both used graphite pencils at first, but it was a fire hazard, so both developed alternatives.

Comment: @Schrodinger's_hat Restful is the way to go. JMX would do the trick too. It was more a comment to the OP. KISS

Comment: **Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.**

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I completely disagree, I learned about RESTful from this question, Regardless about whether people think its better than any other approach is irrelevant because now I have a new resource at my disposal and I can gauge for myself whether it's better than any previous approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a secondary thread, and put it to sleep from time to time, but it is not the best way to spend resources, since this thread will aways be on the runnable pool, spending resource.

```
public void run() {
      while(true) {

         //do everything you need
         try {
            // thread to sleep for 1000 milliseconds
            Thread.sleep(1000);
         } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println(e);
           }
      }
   }
```

You could implement some web service api to, if it is possible to make get or post requests, so this could be a better approach.

Here is a good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

Using Sockets is a good idea too, since it is simple, but remember to let the proxy and the ports you choose aways open, here is a nice example:

Server:

```
public class Servidor {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(12345);
     System.out.println("Port 12345 open!");

     Socket cliente = servidor.accept();
     System.out.println("new client connection " +   
       cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()
     );

     Scanner s = new Scanner(cliente.getInputStream());
     while (s.hasNextLine()) {
       System.out.println(s.nextLine());
     }

     s.close();
     servidor.close();
     cliente.close();
   }
 }
```

Client:

```
public class Cliente {
   public static void main(String[] args) 
           throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
     Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12345);
     System.out.println("Client connected to server!");

     Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
     PrintStream saida = new PrintStream(cliente.getOutputStream());

     while (teclado.hasNextLine()) {
       saida.println(teclado.nextLine());
     }

     saida.close();
     teclado.close();
     cliente.close();
   }
 }
```

Comment: But why the sleep? Not a good idea to just deny service to the client(s).

Comment: Yes, i thought on sleeping thread just to don't overhead the processor, so while the thread is sleeping, it doesn't consume processing power.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a thread and blocking I/O. Keep it simple. A blocked thread doesn't consume any resources at all except the memory for its stack.